# How to test the best combination of ratios to fit inside an overarching ratio?

Tags: combinatorics

We have a problem we are trying to solve where we have a number of different containers. Each container can hold a number of different items (call them "item A" through to "item H"). Each container can handle a different ratio of the items before it is full. So taking just three of the containers the ratios the can handle may be:

**Container 1** may be able to hold the items in the ratio like below:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  2  3  3  3  3  2  1
```

**Container 2** may be able to hold the items in the ratio like below:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  2  3  4  4  3  2  1
```

**Container 3** may be able to hold the items in the ratio like below:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4
```

What we need to try and find out is how to best fit packs of items with smaller ratios with a maximum number of items (say 5 or 6) into the containers. We can find all the different permutations of packs using combinatorics. We have a limit that out of all of the pack ratio permutations we can only select 3 or 4 different ones to use, so have to discard the worst fits and keep the best 3 or 4.

What we are struggling with is a technique that can test for the best of the smaller packs into the larger containers that is both accurate and performant. *Currently we have one or the other!*

Any maths geniuses out there that can help?

Comment: You're after *Math.stackexchange.com* - this is for the software *Mathematica*...

Comment: Thank you. I was sent here from "Programmers Stack exchange"!

This is in the context of an application algorithm, but if the other site is better placed to help, I'll ask on there too.

Comment: I don't see any reference to this site below [your question at programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/298241/how-to-test-the-best-combination-of-ratios-to-fit-inside-an-overarching-ratio). Anyway, the confusion between Mathematica and mathematics is quite common, unfortunately, but not surprising given the small difference in name.

Comment: How odd. It was a linked answer that got me to this site!